# ToolbarLayout turns white on entering again

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

I have implemented a toolbar with a recylerview just like in [the blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). But I have also added a navigation drawer. The toolbar turns white when it enter again after scrolling if I do the following steps

1. Scroll Down The `RecyclerView` so the `Toolbar` would hide
2. Open `NavigationDrawer` by Sliding Left
3. Close `NavigationDrawer` by Closing Right
4. ScrollUp the `RecyclerView`
5. `Toolbar` which appears after this turn white

I know that Toolbar Is still there because I can still click on the menu item inflated in it. It turns to the original color again when I click on the Hamburger Icon in the Toolbar.

Here's is the image on how it turns out
[image]

Here's how I implemented it in code

toolbar.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/container"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:name="aungkyawpaing.yangonuniversity.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start|left"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Also had the same issue. It seems it's a bug in the support-design library. If you have time, please report it to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list.

Comment: Change the layout_height="56dp" of the `AppBarLayout` and move the FrameLayout above the `<AppBarLayout>` and try

Comment: @Ranjith tried and doesn't work. One person has commented on my issue in code.google.com that it's because of image loading in the recycler view

Answer (score 1):

I'm using libraries 23.3.0. and the bug still occurs.

Workaround for this is adding View that takes nearly no space and can be invisible. See the structure below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height=".3dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

for more details please refer https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178037

Answer (score 0):

it is a bug in design library
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178037

> this bug has been solve in Released in v22.2.1.